# LD_PRELOAD, bash and printf

Tags: c, linux, ld-preload

I have a shared object that does some `printf()`s via **attribute** for init; Pretty simple. It just informs me of some variables I have set.

When I do `LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so ./program.sh -flags` the `program.sh` spits out errors due to the printfs:

```
./program_run: line 16: cd: mylib.so: Startup
.: File name too long
./program_run: line 18: test: too many arguments
```

Then the program normally starts up. It looks like the bash script is being corrupted with the `printf()`s when it does checking of variables.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Print to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. Many commands in bash scripts use `stdout` and you cannot just add random text to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this changes:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so ; ./program.sh -flags
```

Does you printf() use the variable arguments?

Comment: One of them does, I'm passing a version number via define, ie: #define VERSION 2.000 then printf("Current Version: %f", VERSION)

Comment: I commented out all of printfs() in the shared object. The bash script doesn't give out errors any longer. trying to maybe look for a way to display text from this module without corrupting what bash does.

Comment: In mylib.so, do you define a new printf? Can i see it?

Comment: void altprintf(char* str, ...)
{
    char buf[256];
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, str);
    vsprintf(buf, str, args);
    va_end(args);

    printf(buf);
}

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./mylib.so ./program.sh -flags
```

Notice the path in front of mylib.so

My experience has been that it's better to use a full path, eg

```
LD_PRELOAD=/home/source/mylib/mylib.so ./program.sh -flags
```

Careful using export as mentioned above.

It can cause all sorts of unintended problems.